# How can I use clipboard.js with a span tag onselect event?

Tags: javascript, html-email, clipboard, copy-paste, selectedtext

I was able to create a simple web-page that uses [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) with a button that pastes predefined text using the
`data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js"` property as the documentation at the clipboard.js site shows, but now I want to place some text in a `<span>` tag and copy it when this text is selected.

However, I don't know how to 'tie' the `data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="span"` properties to a `<span>` tag and cause it to copy the `<span>`'s content with the onselect event.

Are there procedural statements that I can use in javaScript to perform the copying and pasting functions?

My goal is to embed code to copy selected text into the HTML part of an email and allow the recipient of the email to simply copy the selected text to the clipboard so that it can then be pasted from the clipboard into an input text box in a web-application's page.

This would simplify copy/paste on touch-screen devices, such as tablets and cell-phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the selection of the screen and can use 'success' and 'error' event. Read Events and Advance section of the clipboard js

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('button', {
  text: function (trigger) {
     return document.getSelection().toString()
  }
});
```

Comment: I see that you're using a button, which I assume clipboardjs connects to with the click event.  Will this still work if I replace the button with a span tag or the id of the span tag. i.e: '#spanID'?  Does the connected element need a data attribute?  Oh and Thanks!

Comment: You can use any element you want

Comment: Again, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please see iAmADeveloper's comments for the answer.

Thanks, iAmADeveloper.